# Pivot on multiple fields from Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have built an access application for a school management and i have to provide report for student list. The way i have stored my data that looks like following.

```
Student Std Gender  Cast
abc1    1   Male    Cast1
abc2    1   Female  Cast3
abc3    1   Male    Cast2
abc4    1   Male    Cast3
abc5    1   Male    Cast2
abc7    2   Male    Cast2
abc8    2   Female  Cast1
abc9    3   Male    Cast1
abc10   3   Male    Cast3
abc11   3   Female  Cast2
abc12   3   Male    Cast1
```

However, there is demand to view the data in a different format. The way i need out is looks like below:

```
           Male         Female                  
Std Cast1Cast2Cast3  Cast1Cast2Cast3 TotalMale TotalFemale Total
1   1     2    1      0    0    1       4       1           5
2   0     1    0      1    0    0       1       1           2
3   2     0    1      0    1    0       3       1           4
```

I have tried to use pivot for the same. But i am not able to pivot table on multiple columns. So please help to generate query for the demanded output.

Comment: There is a lot to be said for using Excel with Access for analysis. You could also write two crosstabs and join them, but Excel would probably give you a prettier report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish the effect of PIVOTing on multiple fields by concatenating the field values together. For example

```sql
TRANSFORM Count(Student) AS CountOfStudents
SELECT Std
FROM Students
GROUP BY Std
PIVOT Gender & "_" & Cast
```

will return

```
Std  Female_Cast1  Female_Cast2  Female_Cast3  Male_Cast1  Male_Cast2  Male_Cast3
---  ------------  ------------  ------------  ----------  ----------  ----------
  1                                         1           1           2           1
  2             1                                                   1            
  3                           1                         2                       1
```